# Why is my MySql DB Connect failing on New Joomla install

Tags: joomla, mysql

When trying to install Civicrm 4.6.5 onto Joomla 3.4.3 I am getting the following error once the install is started from the install for directory option "Cannot open mysql://root:'rootpassword'@localhost/joomla_db?new_link=true: DB Error: connect failed.". This error is display on a white page with nothing else on it. It is using the correct password for root. Any assistance is welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the apostrophes around the password, they are not required.